# How to combine a .map() with a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, map-function

I have an array and I need, for each element of this array, to `fetch` some data (dependent on the element) and add this data to the element in the array.

To set an example, I will simulate the `fetch` with a Promise (in real life, this will be the answer of a webservice):

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('x'))
let a = ['a', 'b']
a = a.map(x => p.then(y => x + y))
console.log(a)
```

What I expected is to have for the first element (`a`) `p` being called, and upon resolution the result added to `a` (giving `ax`). Same for `b`.

Ultimately I expected a new array `['ax', 'bx']`.

What I get instead is an array of Promises

Being quite new to Promises (which I find in theory wonderful) I have a hard time understanding what went wrong here. **Is it possible to combine `.map()` and asynchronous actions within?**

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely possible to perform asynchronous actions inside of a map. However, at best, the result you will get is an array of promises. You then have to use that array to get the results. It isn't possible for the map to return the results directly because the map returns before the results exist.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Aslo related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626610/array-of-promises

Comment: @KevinB: I belive the second "related" link is exactly my problem. I am still digesting it but it really looks so. Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I expected a new array `['ax', 'bx']`, but what I get instead is an array of Promises

This is exactly what [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) was made for. Of course it doesn't produce a plain array but rather a promise for it, but you cannot avoid that when you're doing anything asynchronous.

```
const promises = a.map(x => p.then(y => x + y))
Promise.all(promises).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Comment: cool - missing `.catch` statements though

Comment: upvoted though :) looks clean

Comment: @DrNio You mean every promise chain should be ended with an error handler? Added.

Comment: This is it, thanks. It also matches the "related" link in KevinB's comment (I flagged myself as duplicate)

Comment: yes @Bergi in the end of a promise-call we should add .catch statements

Comment: Why would you care about such things in such a trivial example ?

Answer (score -1):

Edit: here's a code that works the way you want it to work:

```js
let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('x'))
let a = ['a', 'b']
let c =[]
Promise.resolve(a.map(x => p.then(y => c.push(x + y)))).then(() => console.log(c))
```

Since p.then returns an empty object your map will return an array of empty objects.

PS: You can refactor the code, It's a little too late in my country so would go to sleep now.

Comment: an example would be great

Comment: Edited the original answer @DrNio

Comment: cool - i would add a .catch also. i don't know why it is downvoted - maybe that person can explain why.

Comment: @DrNio It's downvoted because it *doesn't* work. Have a timeout in `p` (instead of immediate resolution) and it falls apart.

Comment: ok thanks for noticing!